# Get value of child node in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I use in my c# WindowsForm weather api that returns me xml file from which i want to get nodes.

```
<current>
     <city id="2988507" name="Paris">
      <coord lon="2.35" lat="48.85"/>
       <country>FR</country>
       <timezone>7200</timezone>
       <sun rise="2020-06-13T03:46:45" set="2020-06-13T19:54:52"/>
     </city>
     <temperature value="67.41" min="66.2" max="69.01" unit="fahrenheit"/>
     <feels_like value="64.31" unit="fahrenheit"/>
     <humidity value="59" unit="%"/>
     <pressure value="1009" unit="hPa"/>
    </current>
```

If I try to get value of temperature and city i have no problem, but when I try to get value of the Country i get null error.

```
using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
{
     string url = web.DownloadString("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + lookedCity + "&mode=xml&units="+tempType+"&appid=70e1d7c5");

     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.LoadXml(url);

     temp = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("temperature").Attributes["value"].Value;
     country = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("country").Value;
     city = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("city").Attributes["name"].Value;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to get `country` from the root element - but it's not, it's within `city`. (This would be easier to tell if you formatted the XML.) So switch the order to fetch `city` first, then use `city.SelectSingleNode("country")`. Although personally I'd use LINQ to XML which would make all of this a little cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to use `InnerText` not `Value` and country is under city.

```
var country = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("city").SelectSingleNode("country").InnerText;
```

This works for your case, but I would suggest you to use linq.